# Javascript array to linked list, and understanding memory

Tags: javascript, memory, linked-list

I have the following code to convert an array to a linked list:

```
function arrayToList(array) {
  var list = null;
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    list = {value: array[i], rest: list};
  return list;
}
```

This code was given to me so I'm trying to understand it.  I get the basic intuition/gist of it (I've worked with linked lists, took a data structures class in Java already, understand basics of pointers in C), etc.

However, something's not clicking and I want to make sure I can see what's going on.  So let's consider we create a variable, **list**, referring to memory space whose value is declared to be *null*.  Let's say this "memory address" of this is *0001*:

*0001*: [*null*] **list**

So what happens after the first iteration of our loop?  This is my interpretation.  **list** now refers to a new chunk of space.  That is, by re-defining **list** in the line:

```
list = {value: array[i], rest: list};
```

we created a "new" object that occupies new space.  So now we might have:

*0001*: [*null*]
*0002*: [*array[i]*] **list.value**
*0003*: [*null*] **list.rest**

(I'm not quite sure where exactly **list** is "pointing" to now, assuming *0002*, though conceptually I guess that's kind of moot in Javascript)

Is this understanding correct?  I'm used to thinking of data structures a la Java, where an object like **list** has already-defined blocks of space every time an instance is created.  I've worked with Python but have not built linked lists with it before.  From this I assume a language like Javascript is fluid in that you can just have a variable be null, then have it refer to a hash, then when you set it to be another hash it creates a "new" hash, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First off, there is no native data structure in *JavaScript* which is a *linked list*, we have *Objects* and we have *Arrays* (which confusingly are special cases of *Objects*).

The code you've shown us here makes *Objects* by using *object literals*.

---

This seems to be more a question about using the same identifier on both sides of an `=`

The variable on the *RHS* of an `=` will point to the thing before it changes on the *LHS*

```
// say we have
var foo = {};

// Then
foo = {"fizz": foo};
```

is equivalent to having

```
var foo = {};

var t = foo;
foo = {"fizz": t}; // `foo` becomes a new object in a different memory location
// that points to `t`s target, meaning that `t` is referencable through `foo` and so
// won't be GC'd if the identifier `t` is cleaned up from namespace
```

You might find this be counter-intuitive based on the usual *left-to-right* order of execution, but if you think about it - you can't "set" until you know what to set, so until the *RHS* has finished you can't update the identifier from the *LHS*

---

So if you loop this, you might end up with a structure like

```
foo;           // Object @ e.g. 0x30
foo.fizz;      // Object @ e.g. 0x20
foo.fizz.fizz; // Object @ e.g. 0x10
foo.fizz.fizz.fizz; // undefined
```

Where each *Object* has it's own hash map which points back to the previous one (when looking up *fizz*) until you run out of *Objects*, and none of the memory gets GCd because each one is still reachable. How an environment actually implements this isn't specified in the spec, so it **isn't a requirement** that the memory location of an *Object* never moves, but it's location in memory is not something you are able to see or interact with (it's all done behind the scenes). Therefore, for all in-environment purposes, you can think of the memory locations as static.

Comment: I think the OP is discussing how a linked list is stored in memory in JavaScript, not how objects are set in this abstracted layer.

Comment: Are you saying that OP's code actually produces a `linked list`?